# How can I pass a particular link when I use PackageManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I want to pass a link of a video and want YouTube app to play that video directly and I want to use following code:

```
btn3.setOnClickListener {
        val i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube")!!
        startActivity(i)
}
```

I don't want to use following code:

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("link of video")))
```

Comment: A launch `Intent`, by definition, does not take a link.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the launch `Intent`, which does not take any arguments, you can call `setPackage()` on your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` to tell the OS to open the desired app:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("link of video")).apply {
  setPackage("com.google.android.youtube")
}
```

You should be careful though, in case the YouTube app is not installed on the device your code will throw an `ActivityNotFoundException`. The best way to guard against this is using [`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) which will return an empty list if there are no Activities that can handle the `Intent`.

Comment: thanks alot. that worked completely fine. I have 1 more query if  i Can use the same with amazon??

Comment: As long as Amazon supports `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` that should work.